# Use of single or double quotes in CLI argument

Tags: shell

I've written a simple php script that must execute via the CLI and it needs two arguments.

```
/usr/local/bin/php myscipt.php arg1 arg2
```

it works well, but IF I put something like

```
/usr/local/bin/php myscipt.php ar"g1 arg2
```

or

```
/usr/local/bin/php myscipt.php ar"g1 ar'g2
```

It does not treat the argument like I want, how can I solve this.

Comment: This seems to be a shell question instead of a php question...

Answer (score 1):

You should be running a Linux shell or similar. Quotes are parts of shell syntax. So you need to escape them.

The way you escape a character in shell depends on the software. But most of them support escaping with a backslash, single quotes or double quotes, e.g.:

```
php script.php \'string\' 'word1 word2 word3'
php script.php "word $shell_variable"
```

Read more about [quoting variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html) and [escaping](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/escapingsection.html)

Answer (score 0):

Execuse me !
I think you did not understant what I mean.
So I'll try to explain more.
The true syntaxe for commande line is

```
/usr/local/bin/php script1.php arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Such the arguments shall not contain " or '
the question is : How to treat in the script "script1.php" the " or ' so to correct them or eraise them.

thanks